# insert database nusoap-complexType

Tags: php, html, output, nusoap

I want to create insert database a web service from :
http://www.discorganized.com/php/a-complete-nusoap-and-flex-example-part-1-the-nusoap-server/

Here's my script :

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/nusoap.php';
$client= new nusoap_client("http://127.0.0.1/test2/index.php", false);
$in_contact=array ('first_name'=>$_POST['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
                'phone_number' => $_POST['phone_number'],);
$result = $client->call('insertContact', $in_contact);
if ($result){
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

despite increasing ID, why the other columns remain empty ?
please help me, thank you.

The `<form>` code..

```
< form action="Contact.class.php" method="GET" > Nama Depan:<br> <input type="text" name="first_name"/><br> Nama Belakang:<br> <input type="text" name="last_name"/><br> Email:<br> <input type="text" name="email"/><br> Telepon:<br> <input type="text" name="phone_number"/><br><br> <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br> < /form >
```

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($_POST);` after `<?php`tag to check if the values are properly getting mapped.

Comment: null input, whether the fault lies in the array that I created ?

Comment: Maybe the `<form>` is not properly sending data to your PHP. Can you show the `<form>` code ?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the method is `GET` , Change that to `POST`

Like this...

```
<form action="Contact.class.php" method="POST" >
```

#### The fixed `<form>` code.. You had a lot of indentations gone wrong..

```
<form action="Contact.class.php" method="POST" >
Nama Depan:<br> <input type="text" name="first_name"/><br>
Nama Belakang:<br> <input type="text" name="last_name"/><br>
Email:<br> <input type="text" name="email"/><br>
Telepon:<br> <input type="text" name="phone_number"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br> </form>
```

Comment: sorry, not successful.

Comment: There is a space between `<` and `form` on your code.. Remove that. **Use the `<form>` code in the answer**

Comment: <form action="Contact.class.php" method="POST" >
Nama Depan:<br> <input type="text" name="first_name"/><br>
Nama Belakang:<br> <input type="text" name="last_name"/><br>
Email:<br> <input type="text" name="email"/><br>
Telepon:<br> <input type="text" name="phone_number"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br> </form>

still can't

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/nusoap.php';
$client= new nusoap_client("http://127.0.0.1/test2/index.php", false);
$in_contact=array ('first_name'=>$_POST['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
                'phone_number' => $_POST['phone_number'],);
$result = $client->call('insertContact', array($in_contact));
if ($result){
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? What did you do and why does it work?

Comment: $result=$client->call('method',array('param1,param2'));

Comment: Sorry i clicked enter without finishing.

Okay so as you can see that we will first call the method which is registered, then the array. However, the array is already specified and therefore only calling $in_contact as result of ($in_contact=array ('first_name'=>$_POST['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
                'phone_number' => $_POST['phone_number'],);)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add any additional information you have to your answer. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)